# Create animation like 3D TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, animation

I want to create `UITableView` like [Zime Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisysteme.zime&hl=en) application.

I don't want code but want some advise that how can we create this type of `UITableView` in iPhone application.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want but may be a little better. Check this library named [Scroller](https://github.com/raweng/Scroller)

You can customise it to have the effect you want instead of building from scratch.